# Eclipse XSD Content Assist, no annotations?

Tags: xml, eclipse, annotations, xsd

I have a XSD fully documented with the `<xs:annotation> <xs:documentation>` elements, but the only content-assist annotation that shows when I hover my mouse over the relevant element is the root element!

The other elements in my file appear in the content-assist box, but without ANY of my documentation. What on earth am I missing here? Solutions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to validate your XSD ?

Comment: your eclipse version and a snippet of code might help too to see what's wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate your XSD with XML Editor from Eclipse Webtool project. It has source editing with autocompletion, validation and most features you'd want. http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/

Its available from the main Indigo update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

Comment: Here's what I'm using:  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version:  Juno Service Release 2. I have webtools.  My schema does validate. I will post it as an edit.

Comment: Update:  Looks like I when I overwrote the files a while back I removed the annotation since they were ineffective and make the schema messy.